# Prevent page reload using JS, unless next or back buttons pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page reload alerts working, however they even happen when a button press is done as this triggers a page reload. How would I prevent a page reload and fire an alert when the page is refreshed, unless its a button press (Input type is Submit)

```
var dont_confirm_leave = 0; //set dont_confirm_leave to 1 when you want the user to be able to leave withou confirmation
var leaveMsg = "Dude, are you sure you want to leave? Think of the kittens!";

window.onbeforeunload = function() {

  if (window.location.href.indexOf("id=website") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("id=partner") > -1) {
    dont_confirm_leave = 1;
  }

  if (document.getElementsByClassName('NextBtn').onclick) {
    dont_confirm_leave = 1;
  }

  if (document.getElementsByClassName('BackBtn').onclick) {
    dont_confirm_leave = 1;
  }

  if (dont_confirm_leave !== 1) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = leaveMsg;
    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //return works for Chrome and Safari
    return leaveMsg;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is a code snippet needed in this post as its not working?

Comment: not sure, i added it cause i thought that was the way to add the JS sample

Comment: you need to add it if your JS itself is displaying any output or if the JS has related html/css which is going to display any output. Its an alternative to JSFiddle. so I think its not required here.If you want keep it try to replicate the whole issue you are having by adding related html/css so other users can visually see what issue you are facing.

Comment: ok cool, have removed the snippet code thing